# How to return an interface from an method which it has implemented?

Tags: go, methods, interface, crud

Sorry if this question is a bit basic.
I am trying to use Golang interfaces to make the implementation of CRUD more dynamic.
I have implemented an interface as follows

```
type Datastore interface {
    AllQuery() ([]interface{}, error)
    ReadQuery() ([]interface{}, error)
    UpdateQuery() ([]interface{}, error)
    CreateQuery() ([]interface{}, error)
    DestroyQuery() ([]interface{}, error)//Im not sure if the return value implementation is correct
}
```

That can be used with a multitude of models `category Category`,`tag Tag`.etc
It implements the methods indicative of the structs which represent the models in the app.

Here is the simplified handler/controller
    func UpdateHandler(c handler.context) error {
        p := new(models.Post)
        return Update(p,c)
    }

This is the function implementing the interface

```
  func Update(data Datastore,c handler.context) error{
        if err := c.Bind(data); err != nil {
              log.Error(err)
        }
        d, err := data.UpdateQuery()
        //stuff(err checking .etc)
        return c.JSON(fasthttp.StatusOK, d)///the returned value is used here
    }
```

This is the method I am using to query the database

```
func (post Post) UpdateQuery() ([]interface{}, error){
//run query using the 
return //I dont know how to structure the return statement
}
```

How do I structure the interface above and the methods it implements so that I can return the result of the query back to the implementing function.
Please let me know if I need to add anything to the question or improve it I will try to do so promptly.
Thanks!

Comment: Your CRUD interface could be better if it is designed similar to [this one](https://godoc.org/github.com/sauerbraten/crudapi#Storage)

Comment: You really should try and come up with a _minimal_ example. And please: get rid of the empty interface. Whatever you try to do, it will be wrong when done with `interface {}`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should store the return value to a variable. Also make sure that this return value (result) is slice of interface.
If it's not then convert it by

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
intf := make([]interface{}, v.Len())
```

In your case your UpdateQuery function might look like

```
func (post Post) UpdateQuery() (interface{}, bool) {

    result,err := []Struct{}

    return result, err
}
```

Demo :
https://play.golang.org/p/HOU56KibUd